# Apache2 create log as root and not as Apache user

Tags: apache

I dont understand why apache2 create log as `root` and not as Apache user. This cause the problem that every day i need to restart the service.

This is my `envvars` configuration for the user:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=myuser
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=myuser
```

And in apache2.conf i have the standard configuration for the user:

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

When i run/restart apache i use the command as root:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you need other information, i can tell you.

EDIT logrotate configuration for apache:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 14
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
                if invoke-rc.d apache2 status > /dev/null 2>&1; then \
                    invoke-rc.d apache2 reload > /dev/null 2>&1; \
                fi;
    endscript
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi; \
    endscript
}
```

This is all the files presents in `logrotate.d`:

```
alternatives  apache2 apport  apt  certbot  dpkg  fail2ban  lxd  mysql-server  nginx  rsyslog  ufw  unattended-upgrades
```

Comment: Actually it is standard that these files belong to the root user. Question is why you need to restart the service because of that.

Comment: Ah.. if its the standard then ok. I was thinking that this was the problem that cause apache2 no longer work after 00:01. The service do not receive any traffic (its on my local server, anybody call it). And in the morning the service no longer works, i simply restart it and works again

Comment: Then you should find out what the actual cause is, right? You do that by checking the log files, currently it sounds like you guess...

Comment: File permissions might very well be the issue, but then most likely it is the log rotation that causes problems which is a separate process. Anyhow, check the apache services error log file to find out why it stops operating.

Comment: I have log file rotation enabled, but if i look error.log there is no error on that. I really dont need log file rotation, so now i will disable that and check tomorrow.

Comment: You definitely need log file rotation, otherwise the files will get longer and longer and finally make your system crash.

Comment: :/ I update my question with apache2 logrotate configuration, but its the standard configuration. I will enable it again and i reply when the service crash next time (tomorrow, i think). I will investigate better on error.log (also if this morning.. was empty)

Comment: And no other, rotated log file exists? Then _certainly_ log rotation is the culprit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184462/discussion-between-mistre83-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here most likely is that you changed the user account the apache http server is operated under without adjusting the configuration of the logrotation accordingly:

```
create 640 root adm
```

So the `logrotate` utility will create new log files with file system permissions your http server process will then not be able to open and write to...